# How to use ^ (start of string) in RegExp

Tags: java, regex

See my work in progress RegExp `Ltd[.'s]{0,2}`
http://rubular.com/r/1FZvA9Nlul

I am running it against this list:

```
Ltd's
Ltd.
Ltd
LtdTestTEst
Ltds
sdfTestLtd
```

How to write a RegExp so that I don't match `sdfTestLtd` and `LtdTestTEst`, which my current RegExp matches.

To further clarify.

I pass above list through java's String.matches() method and I want it to return true only for following pattern:

```
Ltd's
Ltd.
Ltd
Ltds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not need to.

The `^ $` special characters, to signal begin/end of string, are not usually necessary in Java, if using `String.matches()` or equivalent methods, because Java (contrarily to other search/match operators in other languages, and contrarily to Rubular tool) matches the **full string**.

```
   System.out.println("xHello".matches("Hello"));
   // false: no match
   System.out.println("xHello".matches(".*Hello"));
   // true: match
   System.out.println("sdfTestLtd ".matches("Ltd[.'s]{0,2}"));
   // false: no match
```

Comment: +1, although I prefer to be explicit with my regexes to avoid any confusion.

Comment: +1 Thanks for showing example with java code and related informative explanations. Though all other answers are equally correct for my question, but this one contains java example so I chose this one.

Answer (score 5):

This should match your examples exactly: 
`^Ltd('?s|\.)?$`

Answer (score 4):

Put a `^` at the beginning, and a `$` at the end.

http://rubular.com/r/F2VQUUvWLf

Comment: Thanks for showing me rubular.  I didn't know about it.  Nice!

Comment: @dashrb Sure... although it *is* linked to in the question ;)

Answer (score 2):

just put the `^` at the beginning.  I think you might be confused by how the output works.

It appears print just anything you write to the `Match result:` window , but only matches will be highlighted.

if you want to also control the end of string, than you can use `$` for that

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex
`^Ltd[.'s]{0,2}$`